# Usage of Object.keys() equivalent to for in loop?

Tags: javascript

How to use Object.key() for the below for in loop ?

```
for ( const obj in selectedObject) {
     objAdmin[ obj ] = this.adminData.find( function dataInEventType( eT ) {
            return eT[ 'Event Type' ] === newSelectedFilters[ obj ].LabelText;
        } );
     }
```

Comment: `Object.key(selectedObject).forEach(function(obj ){.....})`

Comment: please describe your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this [`forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPvt-io5_UAhUKQY8KHVUqAZEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg&sig2=YgD5QrQpfEHJLyGkRycNDQ) for iterate the array

```
Object.keys(selectedObject).forEach(function(a){
  objAdmin[ a ] = this.adminData.find( function dataInEventType( eT ) {
     return eT[ 'Event Type' ] === newSelectedFilters[ a ].LabelText;

})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns a list of the enumerable keys in an object, it's pretty much the same as

```
var keys = [];
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) keys.push(prop);
}
return keys;
```

This means that you can just iterate over the list returned by `Object.keys()`

```
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    // Do stuff with keys[i]
}
```

It's important to know that `Object.keys()` was defined in ES5 and legacy browsers like IE9 don't support this method, but the function I provided above could be used as a replacement if you would like to support older browsers.

It's also worth noting that there are differences between `for` and `forEach`... I tend prefer to use `for` to be able to `break` out of the loop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(selectedObject).forEach(function(obj){
objAdmin[ obj ] = this.adminData.find( function dataInEventType( eT ) {
            return eT[ 'Event Type' ] === newSelectedFilters[ obj ].LabelText;
        } );
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you add explanation on your answer :)